# CocoaPods doesn't detect the implicit dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I use swift and Xcode 7.1. I have tried all of the steps that are listed in their [troubleshooting guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html) :

- Go to Product > Edit Scheme
- Click on Build
- Add the Pods static library, and make sure it's at the top of the
  list
     Clean and build again
- If that doesn't work, verify that the source for the spec you are
  trying to include has been pulled from GitHub. Do this by looking in
  /Pods/. If it is
  empty (it should not be), verify that the
  ~/.cocoapods/master//.podspec has the correct git hub url
  in it.
- If still doesn't work, check your Xcode build locations settings. Go
  to Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Advanced and set build
  location to "Relative to Workspace".

But it still yeals that the library is not found. I am stuck.

I also have the red library not found problem :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resetting all my Xcode settings to default by tapping this command in the terminal :  `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`. After that, my xcode was reset to its original state.

Then I could use the libraries and everything worked but they would still appear in red. Weird.

So if you are using Xcode 7.1 and having problems with cocoapods, you know what to do. I hope someone will read this one day and fix his problems as well.